# conditional enabling of activeX controls in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, commandbutton

Here is the situation:

I have a sheet, on the sheet i have 4 command buttons as can be seen in the image below. From the image below you can see that the command buttons of the left has 2 colors, red and green. Initially, the 3 buttons would be red and the "Daily Cooling Load Vs Time" would be disabled. The "Daily Cooling Load Vs Time" should only enabled when all the 3 buttons on the left is green.

So here is my problem:

1. How do i initially disable the "Daily Cooling Load Vs Time" button?
2. How do i conditioned so that:

   - when 2 out 3 button is red = "Daily Cooling Load Vs Time" is disabled
   - when 1 out of 3 button us red ="Daily Cooling Load Vs Time" is disabled
   - when all 3 is green= "Daily Cooling Load Vs Time" is enabled

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    If CommandButton1.BackColor = 858083 Then
        CommandButton4.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CommandButton2.BackColor = 858083 Then
        CommandButton4.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CommandButton3.BackColor = 858083 Then
        CommandButton4.Enabled = False
    Else
        CommandButton4.Enable = True
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, you just made a typo in `Else` section (missing *d* in `.Enabled = True`):

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    If CommandButton1.BackColor = 858083 Then
        CommandButton4.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CommandButton2.BackColor = 858083 Then
        CommandButton4.Enabled = False
    ElseIf CommandButton3.BackColor = 858083 Then
        CommandButton4.Enabled = False
    Else
        CommandButton4.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

However, note that `Click` event is not fired if the object is disabled. So in fact, your code can only make `CommandButton4` disabled  but cannot enable it back.

---

If you want `CommandButton4` to be disabled every time you open your workbook you need to paste the code below into `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.CommandButton4.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Instead of `Sheet1` use the code name of the worksheet where this command button is located.

Comment: You could always put this in a loop, would mean any new buttons will work without needing any new if statements

Comment: @99moorem You may be right. But there can also be command buttons on this worksheet that should not be included in this check.

Comment: Tis true just thought i'd put the idea out there

Comment: hey thanks for answering! a quick question tho, how do i make    CommandButton4 to be enabled? @99moorem